# Почему появляется ошибка: arguments is not defined в стрелочной функции?

Tags: javascript

Функция должна находить самый большой интервал между аргументами, которых я не знаю, но при попытке использовать псевдомасив arguments что-то идёт не по плану

```
const maxInterv = () => {
    let maxInterval = 0, temp = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.lenght; i++){
        temp = arguments[i + 1] - arguments[i];
        if (maxInterval < temp) maxInteval = temp;
    }
    console.log(maxInterval);
    return maxInterval;
}
maxInterv(3, 5, 2, 7);
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Стрелочные функции не имеют arguments

Comment: ... но зато есть что повкуснее `(...args)=>args.lenght`

Comment: Да, это в некотором роде мне помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: это даже удобнее, потому как можно применять так `(a, b, ...arg)`

Comment: А еще удобнее использовать обычные `function` и не париться :)